# drawing a map in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a really simple animation of a voyage around the milky way.

```
for k in range(7):
    Rs += k
    Zs += 0.01*k
    for i in range(len(B)):
        print 'i=',i
        for j in range(len(L)):
            MAP[i,j] = DensiteCol(L[j], B[i], 20., 1000.)

    plt.xlabel('l')
    plt.ylabel('b')
    plt.imshow(MAP)
    plt.show()
    #plt.savefig('Q8_'k'.jpg')
```

How can I save an image each time in the loop and save it as different names?

```
MAP[i,j] = DensiteCol(L[j], B[i], 20., 1000.)
```

In this case, is L the axe horizontal or B is?

Comment: sorry, what is your question?

Comment: I want to know in the figure MAP, L is the axe horizontal or B is

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it's useful to get the files in the right order so:

```
plt.savefig("Q8_{:04d}.jpg".format(k))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows:

```
plt.savefig('Q8_' + str(k) + '.jpg')
```